# Как вывести посты через ajax при помощи rest api wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ajax, rest

Пытаюсь вывести все посты при помощи WP REST API при помощи $.ajax, но при переходе к несуществующей странице и завершении скрипта, мне в логи выдает 400 (Bad Request).
Пример кода:

```
    function renderPosts(page = 1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: WPURLS.siteurl + `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=${page}`,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    data.forEach((element) => {
                        // вывод постов
                    });
    
                    renderPosts(++page);
                },
                error: function () {
                    // завершение рекурсии и вывода постов
                    return false;
                },
            });
        }

renderPosts();
```

Все выводится, но в конце выводится ошибка. Хочу понять, может я что-то делаю не так. ?per_page в данном случае мне не нужен. Помогите решить проблемы с выводом постов, чтобы не было ошибки bad request.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/302212

Comment: @XelaNimed Ваш пример не имеет отношения к REST API. Для того чтобы не было такой ошибки, Вам нужно знать количество страниц. При каждом запросе WordPress возвращает 2 заголовка `X-WP-Total` - количество записей в коллекции и `X-WP-TotalPages` - общее количество страниц, охватывающих все доступные записи. Воспользовавшись этими заголовками, Вы можете определить, сколько еще данных доступно в API и не делать очередной запрос на несуществующую страницу. [Документация](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/#pagination-parameters) (пролистайте немного вниз).